# CSS stylesheet not parsed for rules unless I edit the file in the browser's dev tools

Tags: html, css

My CSS stylesheets are not parsed for rules unless I edit the file in the browser's dev tools.

For example, here's a dummy page pulled off of W3 schools:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dummy.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The contents off dummy.css are as follows:

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The background color does not change to blue unless I open up dev tools in the browser and edit dummy.css, either in the style editor or in the sources. Just adding a space somewhere is all it takes, so I'm confident there isn't a syntax problem here.

What is going on?

Comment: Open dev tool settings, go to Network tab in Preferences, make sure "Disable cache (while Devtools is Open) is checked.

Comment: Clear your cache. Try to do a hard refresh CTRL+SHIFT+R

Comment: In addition to clearing cache, close all browsers and reopen them to view your html page.

Comment: Solved it! It wasn't the cache, but rather I discovered that the server I was using was labeling all outgoing files with the header 'Content-Type: text/html'. By adjusting the labeling of the files on the server side to the correct content-type, the problem was solved! Thanks for the tips though, I'll remember that about the cache!